# Node.js Socket.IO Best way to listen room connection?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

**My bad way**

Client-Side

```
socket.on('connect',function(){ socket.emit('EnterRoom',{room:'test'});})
```

Server-Side
app.js

```
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
   socket.on('EnterRoom', function(data) {   
   socket.join(data.room);    
   app.emit('event:JoinRoom',{room:data.room});    
})});
```

some-module-with-rooms.js

```
app.on('event:JoinRoom',function(data){if(data.room=='test'){/*anycode*/} });
```

Comment: yeah :D but 100% that bad way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Wiki](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki) about [Rooms](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms):

> Emitting an event to all clients in a particular room:
>
> `io.sockets.in('room').emit('event_name', data)`

So in your case:

```
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
  socket.on('EnterRoom', function(data) {   
    socket.join(data.room)
    io.sockets.in(data.room).emit('JoinRoom', data);    
  })
});
```

That will emit only to the selected room.
You can the access the room:

```
io.sockets.manager.rooms
```

and i quote the docs:

> This is a hash, with the room name as a key to an array of socket IDs. Note that the room names will have a leading / character

Comment: Hope it helps.. :) Let me know. Take a look a the Wiki, there's a lot of info there

Comment: app.emit('event:JoinRoom',{room:data.room}); - That emit joinroom event on all aplication ...   app.on('event:JoinRoom',function(data){if(data.room=='test'){/*anycode*/} }); ... that listener room join

Comment: Oh, ok... i see. You want to emit that event elsewhere in the server

Comment: What about the client? How can the client listen to a specific room? Thanks